# Just lost with a CSS style

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I feel like making someone else to do my job but I feel really lost here, here's an image of what I got now:

[image: Curretn layout]

Where the two "Anonomymos" are is ment to be the place for tha active users in the chat, however, the more people I add to the chat the `<div>` tag where the message is posted goes under the `<div>` tag for the active users and obviously I want to be shown next to each other.I use a premade CSS style sheet for this, and hope that it could be changed in way to work for my needs, but I have poor knowledge about CSS so I'm not even sure if it is usable in my case, anyways, here is the CSS style that I use at the moment:

```
#ActiveUsers
{

    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 356px;
    background: #E9ECEF;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size : 12px;
   padding:2px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   margin-top:10px;
   margin-left: 60px;

}
#chat
{
  margin: auto;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     width: 356px;
     background: #E9ECEF;
    text-align:left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size : 12px;
    padding:2px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#main {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 600px;
    min-height:150px;
    background: #F1F3F5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size : 12px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#sender
{
    margin-left: 125px;
}
```

And here is the structure in the .php file :

```
<div id="main">
<div id="ActiveUsers"></div>
    <div id="chat"></div>


     <div id="sender">
   Your message: <input type="text" name="msg" size="30" id="msg" />
   <button onclick="doWork(document.getElementById('msg').value);">Send</button>
    </div>
    <span id="logOut">
            <form action="logout.php">
                  <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
            </form>
    </span>
    </div>
```

P.S Just to mention, now the `#ActiveUsers width` is more than the free space but even if I make it 30px, the `#chat <div>` still goes under and under with every new user that is logged.

Comment: I think you are just adding users the wrong way. If I understood well they should be inserted like that "<div id="ActiveUsers">User1, user2, randomnick,user4</div>", while I guess you insert them in seperate <div> tags? I mean <div>user1</div><div>user2 .....

Comment: A nice way to add users would be with a list: `<ul id="activeUsers"><li>User1</li><li>User2</li></ul>` and then css `#activeUsers {list-style:none;} #activeUsers li {display:inline;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that your Active Users are wrapped in some block-element when they are dynamically added to your markup. Based on how it is displayed, I'm guessing that

```
<div id="ActiveUsers"></div>
```

turns into

```
<div id="ActiveUsers"><div>Anonymos</div> <div>Anonymos</div></div>
```

Check to see if your active users are wrapped by any tag. If they're wrapped with a `<div>` tag, you'll need to add this to your CSS:

```
#ActiveUsers div {
    display: inline;
    .
    . /* Your styles here */
    .
}
```

Comment: This almost solve my problem - now the users are shown the way I want, next to the chat window and not above it, but I lost the border.It' not that big of a problem, but in case it's easy way to fix this it would be better to have some border around the users.Thanks anywa, the most important is that now the chat window stays still.

Comment: I guess I'll just stick to this afet all.Works fine for now.